# How to get html tag id when uploading multiple files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this form on my view:
[image: my view]

On my controller I  have the following method:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
// ...
}
```

How can I receive the id of the input tag that was clicked to upload the file? (id=1 or id= 2?

Thank you!!!

Comment: You can’t; the `id` isn’t sent. Just give them different `name`s.

Comment: I think it is usually a good idea to just use the ID value as the name value as well, even though name's don't need to be unique. At least if you follow that convention, there will never be any confusing about which is the key in your POST values.

Comment: But that means that I will have more than one action for the upload - an action per input tag. What if I would have 7 or more tags?

Comment: `file` is received as array on the server so all you have to do is to get the index plus one.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ASP but in PHP you'd do `$files = $_POST['file']` to get the array. Check out @asgoth's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Id is only used to identify the html element on the page, not for submitting to the server. If you don't need to manipulate the data on the client, you even don't need to specify id. By specifying the same name, you can "stack" the files.

So

```
<form action="/action" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
   <input name="file" type="file"></input>
   <input name="file" type="file"></input>
</form>
```

In your controller you receive an array of files.

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase[] file)
{
// ...
}
```

Comment: but if the user uploads only one file (clicks only on one input) then I will not know which one was it..I need some how to add the id of the input tag to the request or something like this..

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="INCLUDE JQUERY"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
$('input[type="file"]').click(){
 $('#id').value = $(this).attr('id');
}
})
function fillId(){}
</script>
<form>

<input type="text" id="id" name="id"/>
<input type="file" id="file1"/>
<input type="file" id="file2"/>
<input type="Submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

*NOTE-this night not be the final code but you get the idea

Comment: Nice! But how the controller will receive the id?

Comment: whenever you will click the type file. the type text will be filled by the id and therefore it value will be posted with the form

Comment: And then I can add a string parameter to the controller action?

Comment: are you sure that the script above popultes the textbox value?

Comment: Because when I try to get the value from the form collection in the controller I receive string empty:(